# looking for a timer to open and close a circuit

Tags: electrical

I am looking to open and close a Feed on a low voltage zone valve on a heating system. Its 16 volt, and I want to put a timer in the line so I can break the current and control the valve with the pre set times of the timer. Most timers I have found are 120 V plug in which is good but only accept 120 V out. I just need a timer that will act like a switch and open and close the 16 V circuit.

Answer (score 1):

All timers act like switches, that open and close the circuit based on time.  The voltage rating is typically based on the maximum voltage that can be switched, not the voltage that must be  switched.

If you're looking at timers that plug into a receptacle, those are designed to turn lamps and such on/off.  That's not the type of timer you want.

You'll want a device that separates the power circuit, from the circuit being controlled.

Comment: I think the OP was referencing the type of timer that plugs into an outlet. Those of course only will switch one side of the circuit between the plug in prongs and the "load" side outlet on the side of the timer module.

Comment: Keywords to find readily-available and easy-to-integrate timers with separate outputs are "dry contact timer" or "pool pump timer". These are available as mechanical and digital timers with all kinds of different features.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing of a product that I could think of to recommend, there is a work around - use a relay on the output of the plug in timer.

[image: Cube relay]

They sell AC 120V relays (we commonly use these orange cube relays as shown above.) The rating on it is the power source, relatively anything on the other side can be switched. You'll still have to buy the timer and include somewhere to mount this and enclose it, but they're pretty cheap and do exactly what you need done.

1. Cut the plug end off of a wire (or create your own)
2. Connect the hot and neutral wires to the coil terminals of the relay (2 and 7 shown above and typical)
3. Your 16V lines would then be tied into the appropriate terminals for switching. As shown above, 1/3 and 8/6 provide normally open switching, 1/4 and 8/5 provide normally closed switching. You're going to want to use a pair of the normally open terminals in this case.
4. Tighten everything down, and first plug this relay into a wall outlet to ensure that it's working as intended. When it's plugged in, it should close the other circuit allowing the 16V to flow to the intended device.
5. Plug in the timer and plug your relay device into it now. So basically when the timer is active, the coil will become powered and 'turn on' the 16V device.

Mounting and all that should be taken into consideration of course, but this gives you the general idea and the electrical layout of the system.